# How to pause further execution until the ajax call is finished in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax, laravel

Actually I am editing some values in form while fetching from database via ajax on clicking an element i am opening a modalbox and fetch the details from server and put them in appropriate form elements.

there is pin code in that data I want to fetch all the areas of that pin code.

when that pin code have been put in the textbox via jQuery I am calling the `keyup()` function of jQuery and that will trigger the event which will call the ajax of Fetching Details Of pincode.

now I want to Fetch Those Details And Put The Appropriate Data in textbox(state) which is perfectly done.

I want to put areas in city dropdown but the problem is I also want to auto select the City which is in database after fetching all the cities of that pincode.

but the problem is modal opens before this process is done and it shows the cities later which is weird.

here is my code

Datatable where the edit button is

```
<div class="block full">
    <div class="block-title">
        <button type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-add-customer" class="btn btn-effect-ripple btn-primary pull-right" style="overflow: hidden; position: relative;"><span class="btn-ripple animate" style="height: 129px; width: 129px; top: -43.5px; left: -20.9844px;"></span><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Add <?php echo $page; ?></button>
        <h2><?php echo $page; ?>s</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="table-responsive">
        <table id="example-datatable" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-vcenter">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th class="text-center" style="width: 50px;">ID</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Email</th>
                    <th>Phone</th>
                    <th style="width: 120px;">Status</th>
                    <th class="text-center" style="width: 75px;"><i class="fa fa-flash"></i></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <?php
                    $labels[0]['class'] = "label-success";
                    $labels[0]['text'] = "Active";
                    $labels[1]['class'] = "label-warning";
                    $labels[1]['text'] = "Pending..";
                    $labels[2]['class'] = "label-danger";
                    $labels[2]['text'] = "Blocked";
                ?>
                @if($customers->count()>0)
                    @foreach ($customers->get() as $customer)
                    <tr>
                        <td class="text-center">{{$customer->id}}</td>
                        <td>{{$customer->name}}</td>
                        <td>{{$customer->email}}</td>
                        <td>{{$customer->phone}}</td>

                        <td><span class="label{{($labels[$customer->status]['class']) ? " " . $labels[$customer->status]['class'] : ""}}">{{$labels[$customer->status]['text']}}</span></td>
                        <td class="text-center">
                            <a href="javascript:void(0)" title="Information" class="btn btn-effect-ripple btn-xs btn-info info" id="info" data-id="{{$customer->id}}"><i class="fa fa-info"></i></a>
                            <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Edit" class="btn btn-effect-ripple btn-xs btn-success edit" id="edit" data-id="{{$customer->id}}"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></a>
                            {{-- <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Delete" class="btn btn-effect-ripple btn-xs btn-danger"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a> --}}
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    @endforeach
                @endif
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Fetching Details From Database

```
//script for edit customer
        $(".edit").click(function(){
            var custid=$(this).attr('data-id');
            $("#custid").val(custid);
            $.ajax({
                url:"/edit-customer",
                method:"post",
                headers: {
                    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                },
                data:{id:custid},
                error: function (error) {
                    console.log(error);
                    $.bootstrapGrowl('<h4><strong>Unsuccess!!!</strong></h4> <p>'+error.statusText+'</p>', {
                        type: "danger",
                        delay: 5000,
                        allow_dismiss: true,
                        offset: {from: 'top', amount: 20},
                        align: "center",
                        width: 400
                    });
                },
                success:function(resp){
                    json=$.parseJSON(resp)
                    // console.log(json);
                    $("#editname").val(json.name);
                    $("#editphone").val(json.phone);
                    $("#editemail").val(json.email);
                    $("#editdob").val(json.birthdate);
                    $("#editpincode").val(json.pincode).keyup();
                    $(document).ajaxStop(function () {
                        $("#editcity").val(json.city).change();
                    });
                    $("#editstate").val(json.state);
                    $("#editaddress").val(json.address);
                    $("#modal-edit-customer").modal("show");
                }
            });
        });
```

Fetching Details Of Pincode

```
//pincode api code to get city and state.
$(".pincode").keyup(function () {
    let pincode = $(this).val();
    if (pincode.length == 6) {
        $(".city option").not(":first").remove();
        $.ajax({
            url: 'https://api.postalpincode.in/pincode/' + pincode,
            type: 'GET',
            error: function (error) {
                // console.log(error);
                $.bootstrapGrowl('<h4><strong>Unsuccess!!!</strong></h4> <p>' + error.statusText + '</p>', {
                    type: "danger",
                    delay: 5000,
                    allow_dismiss: true,
                    offset: {from: 'top', amount: 20},
                    align: "center",
                    width: 400
                });
            },
            success: function (resp) {
                console.log(resp);
                if (resp[0].Status == "Success") {
                    for (var i = 0; i < resp[0].PostOffice.length; i++) {
                        $('.city').append($("<option></option>").attr("value", resp[0].PostOffice[i].Name).text(resp[0].PostOffice[i].Name));
                    }
                    $(".state").val(resp[0].PostOffice[0].State);
                } else if (resp[0].Status == "Error") {
                    $(".state").val("");
                    $.bootstrapGrowl('<h4><strong>Wrong!!!</strong></h4> <p>Pincode is Wrong</p>', {
                        type: "danger",
                        delay: 3000,
                        allow_dismiss: true,
                        offset: {from: 'top', amount: 20},
                        align: "center",
                        width: 300
                    });
                } else {
                    $(".state").val("");
                    $.bootstrapGrowl('<h4><strong>Wrong!!!</strong></h4> <p>Pincode is Wrong</p>', {
                        type: "danger",
                        delay: 3000,
                        allow_dismiss: true,
                        offset: {from: 'top', amount: 20},
                        align: "center",
                        width: 300
                    });
                }
            }
        });
    } else {
        $(".city option").not(':first').remove();
        $(".state").val("");
    }
});
```

Form Modal

```
<!-- Edit Modal Start-->
<div id="modal-edit-customer" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-effect-ripple btn-primary pull-right" data-dismiss="modal"><i class="fa fa-times"></i><i class="fa-solid fa-xmark"></i></button>
                <h3 class="modal-title text-center"><strong>Edit <?php echo $page; ?></</strong></h3>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
            <form id="edit-customer" method="post" class="form-horizontal form-bordered">
                <input type="hidden" name="custid" id="custid" >
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="editname">Name <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <input type="text" id="editname" name="editname" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Name..">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="editphone">Phone No.<span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <input type="text" id="editphone" name="editphone" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter the Phone No...">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="editemail">Email <span class="text-danger"></span></label>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <input type="text" id="editemail" name="editemail" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter your valid email..">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="editdob">DOB <span class="text-danger"></span></label>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <input type="date" id="editdob" name="editdob" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter birthdate..">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="editpincode">Pincode <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <input type="text" id="editpincode" name="editpincode" class="form-control pincode" placeholder="Enter Your Pincode...">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="editcity">City <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <select id="editcity" name="editcity" class="form-control city">
                            <option value="">--Please Select City--</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="editstate">State <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <input type="text" id="editstate" name="editstate" class="form-control state" placeholder="State..." readonly>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="editaddress">Address <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                    <div class="col-md-9">
                        <textarea id="editaddress" name="editaddress" rows="7" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Your Address.."></textarea>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group form-actions">
                    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-3">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-effect-ripple btn-primary">Submit</button>
                        <button type="reset" class="btn btn-effect-ripple btn-danger">Reset</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- Edit Modal End-->
```

function to get data from database in laravel/php

```
public function edit(Request $request)
    {
        $customer=Customer::find($request->id);
        return json_encode($customer);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was thinking something like:

```js
$(document).ajaxStop(function () {
    $("#editcity").val(json.city).change();
    $("#modal-edit-customer").modal("show");
});
```

Or

```js
$(document).ajaxStop(function () {
    $("#editcity").val(json.city).change(function() {
        $("#modal-edit-customer").modal("show");
    });
});
```

> Fetching Details From Database - script for edit customer

because that's where your calling the model show but ajaxStop is probably running after that to load the city data hence there weird model before data your seeing. Based on what you posted in your follow up question i would say you should be able to do this

```js
$("#editpincode").val(json.pincode).keyup(function() {
  $("#editstate").val(json.state);
  $("#editaddress").val(json.address);
  $('#editaddress').on("custom", function() {
    $("#modal-edit-customer").modal("show");
  });
  $("#editcity").val(json.city).trigger("custom");
});
```

Dose this help ?

Answer (score 0):

Could you move the  $("#modal-edit-customer").modal("show"); inside the ajaxStop function after the $("#editcity").val(json.city).change(); even look to use jquery chaining so that the model call can only come after the city data has loaded ? I hope this helps

Comment: is this how you suggest i should do?
`$("#editpincode").val(json.pincode).keyup(function(){
  $("#editstate").val(json.state);
  $("#editaddress").val(json.address);
  $("#editcity").val(json.city).change(function(){
    $("#modal-edit-customer").modal("show");
  });
});`